# Integral estimate

Tags: functional-analysis

given the following scalar product:

$\langle \cdot ,\cdot\rangle _0: L^2(D)\times L^2(D)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (f,g)\mapsto \int_Dfgdx$

$\langle \cdot ,\cdot\rangle_1: C^\infty_0(D)\times C^\infty_0(D)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (f,g)\mapsto \int_D\partial_{x_1} f\partial_{x_1} g+\partial_{x_2}f\partial_{x_2}g dx$

Where $C^\infty_0(D):=\{f\in C^\infty(D,\mathbb{R}):\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset D\}$ and $D\subset[-d,d]^2$

Want to show: $\mid\mid f\mid\mid_0\leq2d\mid\mid f\mid\mid_1$ for all $f\in C^\infty_0(D)$

As an advice I have that $f(x_1,x_2)=\int_{-d}^{x_1}\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)ds$ which also need to be shown...
So I applied the hint to $f^2$:

$f(x_1,x_2)^2=(\int_{d}^{x_1}\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)ds)^2 \overset{\mathrm{Jensen}}{\leq} \int_{d}^{x_1}(\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2))^2ds$

I think I am not so far... Is there some way to estimate the above inequality such that It remains $2d(\partial_{x_1}f(x_1,x_2)^2+\partial_{x_2}f(x_1,x_2)^2)$

May be using the gradient? using the fact that $\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2))^2\leq\partial_{x_1}f(x_1,x_2))^2+\partial_{x_2}f(x_1,x_2))^2=(\nabla f)^2$

Comment: Please check the indices in you definitions: you wrote $0$ in both cases.

Comment: Note that your definition of $C^\infty_0(D)$ is not the usual one. I guess $D$ should be the open one $D = (-d,d)^2$ and $f \in C^\infty_0(D)$ should have compact support (Or your inequality is not true by putting $f=$constant)

Comment: yes.. sorry. actually D is a subset of the cube $[-d,d]^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(x_1,x_2)\in D$ the following estimate holds,

$$|f(x_1,x_2)|^2=|\int_{-d}^{x_1}\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)ds|^2\leq(\int_{-d}^d|\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)|ds)^2$$

$$\leq 2d\cdot\int_{-d}^d|\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)^2+\partial_{x_2}f(s,x_2)^2|ds$$

where the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality was used in the last step.

Hence,

$$||f||_0^2=\int_D|f(x_1,x_2)|^2d(x_1,x_2)\leq\int_{-d}^d\int_{-d}^d|f(x_1,x_2)|^2d(x_1,x_2)$$

$$\leq\int_{-d}^d\int_{-d}^d( 2d\cdot\int_{-d}^d|\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)^2+\partial_{x_2}f(s,x_2)^2|ds)\;dx_1dx_2$$

$$=\int_{-d}^d(\int_{-d}^d|\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)^2+\partial_{x_2}f(s,x_2)^2|ds)\int_{-d}^d2d\;dx_1dx_2$$

$$=4d^2\int_{-d}^d\int_{-d}^d|\partial_{x_1}f(s,x_2)^2+\partial_{x_2}f(s,x_2)^2|dsdx_2=4d^2||f||_1^2$$